# UIView и Codable

Tags: ios, swift

Как реализовать соответствие UIView протоколу Codable? Или это возможно только для NSCoding? Задача сохранить UIView и его состояние в памяти между запусками app.

Answer (score 2):

Для соответствия протоколу уже существующих классов можно использовать [extenstion](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)

```
extension UIView: Codable {
    // MARK: - Decodable
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // your implementation
    }

    // MARK: - Encodable
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

Но для вашей задачи я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону [UI Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches/about_the_ui_restoration_process)

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать.